# slideshow/carousel and background img

Tags: html, css, background, carousel, slideshow

I want to add a slideshow (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) to the first page between navigation and footer and a background image to the next pages between footer and navigation. How can I do it?

Example:
Page 1: slideshow,
Page 2: background img,
Page 3: background img (like page 2),
Page 4: background img (like page 2)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(https://previews.123rf.com/images/doimogoju/doimogoju1404/doimogoju140400084/27771522-Fussball-Fu-ballplatz-Stadion-Gras-Linie-Ball-Hintergrundtextur-Licht-Schatten-auf-dem-Rasen-Lizenzfreie-Bilder.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #0c0;
}

main {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  border: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, .9);
}

footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<main>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text Text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
</main>

<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: set div for each page with id and write css code for each div

Answer (score 0):

try it for `carousel slider` in `first page`

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(https://previews.123rf.com/images/doimogoju/doimogoju1404/doimogoju140400084/27771522-Fussball-Fu-ballplatz-Stadion-Gras-Linie-Ball-Hintergrundtextur-Licht-Schatten-auf-dem-Rasen-Lizenzfreie-Bilder.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #0c0;
}

main {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  border: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, .9);
}

footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>


<main>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/doimogoju/doimogoju1404/doimogoju140400084/27771522-Fussball-Fu-ballplatz-Stadion-Gras-Linie-Ball-Hintergrundtextur-Licht-Schatten-auf-dem-Rasen-Lizenzfreie-Bilder.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/doimogoju/doimogoju1404/doimogoju140400084/27771522-Fussball-Fu-ballplatz-Stadion-Gras-Linie-Ball-Hintergrundtextur-Licht-Schatten-auf-dem-Rasen-Lizenzfreie-Bilder.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/doimogoju/doimogoju1404/doimogoju140400084/27771522-Fussball-Fu-ballplatz-Stadion-Gras-Linie-Ball-Hintergrundtextur-Licht-Schatten-auf-dem-Rasen-Lizenzfreie-Bilder.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
  <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text Text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
</main>

<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```